# nuxt.js and synfusion ej2 navigation menu

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, syncfusion

I'm not clear on how to pass the returned data from an api to the navigation component from syncfusion, any thoughts on how to why this.data is not being sent as a dataSource?

```
<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import { TreeViewPlugin } from '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-navigations';

Vue.use(TreeViewPlugin);

export default Vue.extend({
    //name: 'app',
    data: function() {
        return {
          data: [],
          fields: { dataSource: data, id: 'id', text: 'name', child: 'children' },
        }
    },
    async fetch() {
        const { data } = await this.$http.$get('http://api-call');
        this.data = data.resource.treeNav;
    }

})
</script>
```

The returned array from the api call is:

```
[
            {
            id: '01',
            name: 'Local Disk (C:)',
            expanded: true,
            children: [
              { id: '01-01', name: 'Program Files..' },
              { id: '01-02', name: 'Users' },
              { id: '01-03', name: 'Windows'}
            ]
          }
        ]
```

Comment: The returned data appears to be an array.  Are you trying to access a `resource` property on it?

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your reported problem with shared code snippet. We found that your are updating the datasource on variable declared in the datasource property.

In TreeView, you need to update the datasource in the fields settings of TreeView component instead updating your variable.

Please, refer the below code snippet.

this.$refs.treeview.fields = {
dataSource: dataSource,
id: "code",
text: "name",
child: "countries",
};

Please, refer the below sample link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-qzohm?file=/src/App.vue

Please, refer to the below links for TreeView component.

UG Documentation- https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/treeview/getting-started/

Demo link- https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/demos/#/material/treeview/default.html

API reference- https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/api/treeview/

Regards,
Sowmiya.P